# My BroadcastReceiver is not receiving the BOOT_COMPLETED intent after my N1 boots

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-intent, intentfilter

I am unable to get my BroadcastReceiver onReceive method called using the BOOT_COMPLETED intent.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.jerrellmardis.umbrella"
      android:versionCode="4"
      android:versionName="1.0.3">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <activity android:name=".activities.Umbrella" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.Preferences" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <receiver android:name="com.jerrellmardis.umbrella.receiver.WeatherStartupReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".service.WeatherUpdateService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.jerrellmardis.umbrella.service.WeatherUpdateService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</manifest>
```

**WeatherStartupReceiver.java**

```
package com.jerrellmardis.umbrella.receiver;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.Contacts.People;
import android.util.Log;

import com.jerrellmardis.umbrella.R;

public class WeatherStartupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

       private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
       private int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID;

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // Do something interesting here...
       }
}
```

Comment: oracleicom, how did the problem was solved. please tell

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All the applications that receive the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast must be installed on the internal storage because Android delivers `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast before the external storage is mounted to the device.

To ensure that your application will be installed on the internal memory you just need **NOT** to declare the `android:installLocation` manifest attribute.

Another option is to set the following in the manifest section: `android:installLocation="internalOnly"`

You can find more information about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html).

Comment: Your link includes a period which causes a 404. Removing the trailing period solves the issue. Edit submitted.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Forget everything, I've found a better explanation.

You have to define your receiver with exported = true and enabled = true

```
<receiver android:name="com.jerrellmardis.umbrella.receiver.WeatherStartupReceiver"
  android:enabled="true" 
  android:exported="true" 
>
```

---

I think that if you change this line

```
<receiver android:name="com.jerrellmardis.umbrella.receiver.WeatherStartupReceiver">
```

for this

```
<receiver android:name=".WeatherStartupReceiver">
```

it will fix your problem.

I tried it on one of my projects and it didn't start.

Comment: I don't know why you've been having problems, but I certainly haven't had to declare enabled and exported for my BOOT_COMPLETED receivers to receive notifications.

Comment: I've reread the android documentation about this, and certainly they say that both enabled and exported properties are set by default "true"... Again I'm wrong :S. I don't see anything else strange on oracleicom's code

Comment: So change the name of the receiever to ".WeatherStartupReceiver" even though the class is not at the root of my app dir? The current directory structure is <APP_HOME>/receiver/WeatherStartupReceiver.java

Comment: So I tried changing the name of the receiver in the AndroidManifest but that didn't work. Just to make sure I wasn't noticing that the method was being called, I changed the receiver's onReceive method to throw an exception and still nothing.

Comment: Try another thing, remove the R import. R is resolved automatically.

Comment: Actually I'm just throwing an exception right now so the isn't an R import in the code. And it's still not working :-(

Comment: SOLVED!!! It wasn't working because the app was being installed on the SD card, thus missing the BOOT_COMPLETED intent. THANKS FOR ALL YOUR HELP EVERYONE!