# Android boot service never starts

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, startup

I'm new in Android programming.
I have a receiver that starts a service at boot but it seems never started. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
I don't know how to debug it. Can you explain me how can I debug Android startup services too?

Here is my code. Thank you in advance

Recibidor.java:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Recibidor extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Toast.makeText(context, "Iniciando Recibidor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      final String TAG = "Recibidor";
      Log.i(TAG, "Iniciando Recibidor");

      if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
         Toast.makeText(context, "Iniciando Intent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         Log.i(TAG, "Iniciando Intent");

         Intent servicio = new Intent();
         servicio.setAction("com.pruebas.Servicio");
         context.startService(servicio);

         Log.i(TAG, "Iniciando Servicio");
         Toast.makeText(context, "Iniciando Servicio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

   }
}
```

Servicio.java

```
package com.pruebas;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Servicio extends Service {
   private final String TAG = "Servicio";


   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      Log.i(TAG, "ON CREATE");
      Toast.makeText(this, "ON CREATE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      Log.i(TAG, "ON DESTROY");
      Toast.makeText(this, "ON DESTROY", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      startForeground(0, null);
      Log.i(TAG, "ON START COMMAND");
      Toast.makeText(this, "ON START COMMAND", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return START_STICKY;
   }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pruebas"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application>
        <service android:name=".Servicio">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.pruebas.Servicio"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service> 

        <receiver android:name=".Recibidor" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" 
android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Do you receive the intent in your Recibidor ?

Comment: Hi Entreco. Can you tell me how can I know if I'm receiving the intent?

Comment: You can put logging in onReceiver method

Comment: How can I restart my emulator to make the Receive boot competed event and execute my service? In Eclipse I run the service and starts the emulator, but I think the event is received before my service is intalled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you've posted will never work on later versions of Android. To prevent malware, with later versions of Android, it is not possible to automatically register a `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest *UNTIL* the user has manually started your app from the app launcher.

You will need to create an `Activity` with the MAIN/LAUNCHER `<intent-filter>` entries. Once the user has manually started the app once, the manifest registration for your `BroadcastReceiver` will occur and it will remain registered unless the user uses 'Force Stop` from the Manage Applications part of Settings.

Answer (score 1):

The application needs to be installed in internal storage to receive the BOOT_COMPLETED intent. See this question: [My BroadcastReceiver is not receiving the BOOT_COMPLETED intent after my N1 boots. Help Please!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935321/my-broadcastreceiver-is-not-receiving-the-boot-completed-intent-after-my-n1-boot)

Comment: android:installLocation="internalOnly" means the app is installed in internal only.. to recive any broadcat u hav 2 run the app once .. and please log the reciver in else too

Comment: the application have  the tag android:installLocation="internalOnly". It's installed in internall storage

Answer (score 0):

Try to move

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

out of "receiver" tag.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#perms

Comment: Make sure that you put your service and broadcast receiver inside root package. Or just use fully qualified name (with package).